# Is it possible to get successful results from a Task.WhenAll when one of the tasks fails?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

Given the following:

```
var tPass1 = Task.FromResult(1);
var tFail1 = Task.FromException<int>(new ArgumentException("fail1"));
var tFail2 = Task.FromException<int>(new ArgumentException("fail2"));

var task = Task.WhenAll(tPass1, tFail1, tFail2);
task.Wait();
```

the call to task.Wait() throws an `AggregateException`, whose inner exceptions contain the `fail1` and `fail2` exceptions. But how can I access the `tPass1` successful result?

Is this possible?

I'm aware that I can get the result from the individual task after the `WhenAll` has finished, via `tPass1.Result` however is there a way to get them in an array to avoid having to manually track all the things feeding into the `WhenAll`?

Comment: You are passing array of tasks to `Task.WhenAll`, can you use same array to observe results?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.status?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You will of course need a List<Task> or an array to track the results. There is no fairy to do it for you. Not clear if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @HenkHolterman basically yes I'm asking for a fairy to track the results for me; Task.WhenAll is already tracking the results for the case where there are no exceptions, and it's already tracking the exceptions. I was hoping that there was simply some way to expose that existing information

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a task fails we cannot access its [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) property because it throws. So to have the results of a partially successful `WhenAll` task, we must ensure that the task will complete successfully. The problem then becomes what to do with the exceptions of the failed internal tasks. Swallowing them is probably not a good idea. At least we would like to log them. Here is an implementation of an alternative `WhenAll` that never throws, but returns both the results and the exceptions in a [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) struct.

```
public static Task<(T[] Results, Exception[] Exceptions)> WhenAllEx<T>(
    params Task<T>[] tasks)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tasks);
    tasks = tasks.ToArray(); // Defensive copy
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t => // return a continuation of WhenAll
    {
        T[] results = tasks
            .Where(t => t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            .Select(t => t.Result)
            .ToArray();
        AggregateException[] aggregateExceptions = tasks
            .Where(t => t.IsFaulted)
            .Select(t => t.Exception) // The Exception is of type AggregateException
            .ToArray();
        Exception[] exceptions = new AggregateException(aggregateExceptions).Flatten()
            .InnerExceptions.ToArray(); // Flatten the hierarchy of AggregateExceptions
        if (exceptions.Length == 0 && t.IsCanceled)
        {
            // No exceptions and at least one task was canceled
            exceptions = new[] { new TaskCanceledException(t) };
        }
        return (results, exceptions);
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Usage example:

```
var tPass1 = Task.FromResult(1);
var tFail1 = Task.FromException<int>(new ArgumentException("fail1"));
var tFail2 = Task.FromException<int>(new ArgumentException("fail2"));

var task = WhenAllEx(tPass1, tFail1, tFail2);
task.Wait();
Console.WriteLine($"Status: {task.Status}");
Console.WriteLine($"Results: {String.Join(", ", task.Result.Results)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Exceptions: {String.Join(", ", task.Result.Exceptions.Select(ex => ex.Message))}");
```

Output:

```
Status: RanToCompletion  
Results: 1  
Exceptions: fail1, fail2
```

Comment: Good answer. `ContinueWith` is always a great help with `Task`s.

Comment: @Alex, `async-await` leads to much more cleaner and readable code, and have much lighter implementation then continuation, where you should remember to use `ExecuteSynchronously` options.

Comment: @Basin this is true. With `await` in library code you must remember to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` though. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ConfigureAwait(false) case depends on scenario, it is not a must. Suppose if capturing the context is actually required within library itself.

Comment: @SarveshMishra this is even worse then. You must ConfigureAwait(true/false) case by case. Easy to make an error. The more awaits, the more possibilities for error.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, in .NET Core you don't need to use `ConfigureAwait`.

Comment: @Fabio [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45638071/11178549) it says that for library .NET Core code it is recommended to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, there it says as well when you don't need it, which for .NET Core libraries is most of the time.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe

```
public async Task<Task[]> RejectFailedFrom(params Task[] tasks)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        // Handle failed tasks maybe
    }

    return tasks.Where(task => task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).ToArray();
}
```

Usage

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.FromResult(1),
    Task.FromException<int>(new ArgumentException("fail1")),
    Task.FromException<int>(new ArgumentException("fail2"))
};

var succeed = await RejectFailedFrom(tasks);
// [ tasks[0] ]
```

Comment: You can also use `tasks.Where(t => t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)`
It checks the `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` status for you

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with @Theodor Zoulias's powerfull and elegant [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889692/10958092) pushed me to something. It looks hacky, but still works. One can continue `Task.WhenAll` with something that will not throw an exception for sure (e.g. `_ => { }`) and `Wait` that something.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.Cancel();
var canceled = Task.Run(() => 1, cts.Token);

var faulted = Task.FromException<int>(new Exception("Some Exception"));

var ranToCompletion = Task.FromResult(1);

var allTasks = new[] { canceled, faulted, ranToCompletion };

// wait all tasks to complete regardless anything
Task.WhenAll(allTasks).ContinueWith(_ => { }).Wait();

foreach(var t in allTasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Task #{t.Id} {t.Status}");
    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
        foreach (var e in t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{e.Message}");
    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        Console.WriteLine($"\tResult: {t.Result}");
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
Task #2 Canceled
Task #1 Faulted
        Some Exception
Task #5 RanToCompletion
        Result: 1
```

Comment: _Powerful_, but far away of _elegant_ ;)

Comment: @Basin, it depends on. As for me, less code is better code. This one is as short as possible.

Comment: Sorry, but `ContinueWith` approach produce much more code then approach with `await`

Comment: It is produced behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConcurrentQueue<Exception> errorList = new();

var someTasks = makeSomeActionAsync().ContinueWith(x => 
{
   if(x.Exception !=null)
      errorList.Enqueue(x.Exception);
});

await Task.WhenAll(someTasks);

if(errorList.Any())
   throw new Exception($"\n{string.Join("\n", errorList )}");
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
var task = Task.WhenAll(tPass1, tFail1, tFail2);
task.Wait();
```

to

```
var all = new Task<int>[] { tPass1, tFail1, tFail2 }
    .Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
var task = Task.WhenAll(all);
task.Wait();
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mbggds)

Comment: Looks nice. But are you sure it will work with really long-running tasks? In the example faults can happen immediately, like synchronously.

Comment: Didn't concider yet. Will check later.

Comment: I see that took you awhile,)

Comment: @Alex It's never too late.