# Task.WhenAll to continue even if there are exceptions in HttpClient

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a very simple process that I am trying to figure out how to use `Task.WhenAll` to download multiple pages using `HttpClient`, but if any of the urls throws an exception, even the one that succeeded dont seem to give me the content page.

1. Take a list of urls
2. Use `HttpClient` `.GetStringAsync`
3. Process the ones that succeeded
4. Get list of all the urls that failed (this might make things messy, if so this is not 100% a requirement)

Here is my code, how can i make it so that if any fail, the remaining will be in `pages`

`urls` is `List<string>` contains list of urls

```
try
{
    var tasks = urls.Select(x => httpClient.GetStringAsync(x));
    var pages = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    //pages will be an array of all the ones that got download without errors

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //not sure how to properly get the ones that failed
    Console.WriteLine(e);

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888744/34092

Comment: You could start by combining each url with its associated task in a custom class or [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2). Then after awaiting all the tasks you could filter the urls that have their task faulted: `Where(entry => entry.Task.IsFaulted).Select(entry => entry.Url)`.